# How hard is reconstructing a permutation from its differences sequence?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, permutations, np

My interest in combinatorially motivated computational problems led me to search for simple problems that turn out to be computationally hard. In this pursuit, I came up with a problem which I hope is NP-complete. I searched the literature without finding an equivalent or close problem.

Originally motivated by this post, [Can you identify the sum of two permutations in polynomial time?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18037/can-you-identify-the-sum-of-two-permutations-in-polynomial-time/18045#18045) , and my interest in computational properties of permutations.

A differences sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n$  of a permutation $\pi$ of numbers $1, 2, \ldots n+1$ is formed by finding the difference between every two adjacent numbers in the permutation $\pi$. In other words, $a_i= |\pi(i+1)-\pi(i)|$ for $1 \le i \le n$

For example, sequence $1, 1, 3$  is the differences sequence of permutation $2 3 4 1$.  While, sequences $2, 2, 3$ and $ 3, 1, 2$ are not the differences sequence of any permutation of numbers $1, 2, 3, 4$.

> Is there an efficient algorithm to determine whether a given sequence is the differences sequence for some permutation $\pi$, or is it NP-hard?

We get computationally equivalent problem if we formulate the problem using circular permutations.

Cross posted on TCS SE without an answer. [Efficient algorithm for existence of permutation with differences sequence?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18255/efficient-algorithm-for-existence-of-permutation-with-differences-sequence)

**EDIT** Marzio's nice NP-completeness proof has been published in the [Electronic Journal of Combinatorics](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v21i4p3).

Comment: +1. Great question!

Comment: i think you  should sort   sequence into ascending order and  if  you sum adjacent elements and get distinct elements in the list then it could be difference of some permutation.is not it?

Comment: I'm not sure that I get your idea. Do you a have an algorithm?

Comment: The problem is NP complete it is not NP hard.It can be reduced to (in fact it is equivalent to) boolean SAT. The good news may be that your particular version just may not be in the list of NP complete problems

Comment: @ARi Could you give a reference or explanation for your claim. Also, this should then be an answer.

Comment: For an alphabet of s=$2^b$ symbols and a **difference string** of n symbols (b.n bits) ie $D_j$; an **input string** $W_i$ of n+1 symbols (b.$\overline{n+1}$ bits) is required such that the boolean cct: cctCreateDifferenceString($W_i$)&$D_j$ = 1 hence we see that if the boolean cct *["cctCreateDifferenceString" + "n bit '&' gate - with inputs tied to $D_j$"]* is satisfied the OPs problem is solved.

Comment: @ARi I don't see a proper NP-completeness reduction. Are you trying to build a reduction from Circuit-SAT problem?

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany Yes as I initially commented.The proof that  your "Permutation reconstruction Problem" $\leq_p$ [Boolean SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) is trivial, going by the lines I give above.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I don't see how your idea leads to NP-completeness proof.

Comment: That won't work. You have to give a reduction from Boolean SAT. i.e.  Boolean SAT $\le_p$ Permutation reconstruction Problem.

Comment: Sorry thats what i meant

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried to give a formal proof of the NP-completeness of the problem.

For the reduction details see my answer on [cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18255/efficient-algorithm-for-existence-of-permutation-with-differences-sequence/18345#18345)

Comment: I am looking forward to the addictive smartphone-app version of the Crazy Frog puzzle!