# Recognizing sequences sortable by transpositions?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity

While reading the post, [*Probability of generating a desired permutation by random swaps*, by Aaronson](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25427/probability-of-generating-a-desired-permutation-by-random-swaps), and to continue my program I started in this post,  [How hard is reconstructing a permutation from its differences sequence?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135968/how-hard-is-reconstructing-a-permutation-from-its-differences-sequence), I got interested in this problem of sorting:

**Input**: a sequence $A$ of $2N$ positive integers (may contain repeated integers).

**Question**: Is it possible to sort sequence $A$ using $N$ transpositions?

Each transposition swaps two non-adjacent elements $a_i$ and $a_j$ in $A$ (two elements are not adjacent if $|i−j|>1$). This means that the two elements can not be adjacent in $A$. I guess the problem should be $NP$-complete.

> Is this problem $NP$-complete? Is there an obvious Karp reduction from the $NP$-hard problem in Aaronson's post?

This was posted on [TCS SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27858/recognizing-sequences-sortable-by-transpositions) and had a bounty but without an answer.

P.S. This problem has a nice geometric interpretation: It is equivalent to deciding the existence of a path of length at most N between two points on a special [2N-Permutahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).

Special permutahedron means that two nodes are connected by an edge if and only if the corresponding permutations are separated by one non-adjacent transposition.

[image: Permutahedron of order 4]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by swapping *non*-adjacent entries. Usually we consider either all transpositions, or adjacent transpositions. Paths on the permutohedron definitely correspond to sequences of adjacent transpositions. Also, there is a very simple polynomial time algorithm to decide if you can get from one permutation to another using a given number of adjacent transpositions (because of the definition of "length" of an element of the symmetric group in terms of inversions)

Comment: @SamHopkins  It means swapping integers in two non-adjacent positions inside the array. Special permutahedron means that two nodes are connected by an edge if and only if the corresponding permutations are separated by one non-adjacent transposition.

Comment: So the picture is not supposed to depict this “special permutohedron”? E.g., there is an edge between 1234 and 1324 in the picture, but that’s an adjacent swap, right?

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes, that's right.

Comment: What is the Coxeter structure if you take all non-adjacent transpositions as generators and only the $(g_i g_j)^{m_{ij}}$ type relations. This doesn't quotient by nearly enough to get to $S_N$, but it is computationally nice.